# freebasic falla al salvar un vector como binario

Tags: array, lista, windows, archivo, validación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][[image: ][1]]

Al realizar un port a freebasic de un programa muy similar a otros que tengo ya plenamente operativos en otros entornos me he encontrado con que subsecuentemente a la definición por el algoritmo de un vector no era almacenado en la forma debida al intentar hacerlo por las tres siguientes sentencias

Open NameC For Binary Access Write As #1

Put #1, , C()

Close #1

Inicialmente o bien se creaba el archivo y quedaba vacío, o bien ni se creaba. A resultas de ello creé un programita que testeaba Put y la recuperación por Get que para vectores de elementos ubyte generados aleatoriamente pruébase tanto Put como Get funcionan debidamente.

Modificado el algoritmo que da el fallo a un vector más corto (en lugar de 48 bytes sólo 8) el fallo sigue produciéndose en la variación que corresponde a la imagen más grande que se acompaña. Sólo el primer elemento del vector se graba, y el resto queda en ceros  (presumiblemente) como procedente de una inicialización, o de pérdida de datos en la transferencia). Se constata que el fallo se produce al momento del uso de Put, pues si intentamos recuperar con Get subsecuentemente a la creación del archivo por Put, lo recuperado es ya defectuoso.

He constatado igualmente que si hago el vector manualmente, lo graba bien Put y lo recupera bien Get; de manera que el código de mi programa contiene la causa determinante del fallo, por chocante que sea ver en pantalla un vector as ubyte de 8 Bytes (de 0 A 255 en valor) no ser debidamente grabado -sin sentencia otra intermedia alguna- a archivo subsecuentemente por Put.

Aparte de proseguir la depuración del código para conseguir la funcionalidad en este entorno, lo que realizaré en tanto (y hasta donde) pueda, mi pregunta es ¿alguien tiene experiencia de este problema y puede compartir los pasos a seguir para evitarlo?

Aunque he expresado en previas instancias de mi cuestión mis sospechas de posibles causas, relacionadas más bien con dificultades sufridas con freebasic al hacer algún programa, la cuestión es que el nexo causal no está establecido. Lo que sí tengo para mí como probado es que si experimentas que tras intentos repetidos de depuración el programa (o módulo de) no corre bien, es eficaz bien re-empezar desde cero, o si hay la suerte de tener algo similar que no muestra el impedimento sufrido (es el caso de esta vez) simplemente introduces lo imprescindible y quitas lo que no va con tu intento, y es así como las más de las veces (para los casos difíciles, digamos) aumenta la posibilidad de que el asunto quede resuelto. Al empezar desde cero eliminas (en principio) cualquier fuente de problema que no detectes sea la causa del mismo, y al reusar un programa similar que funciona como plantilla, tienes alguna probabilidad de que no incurras en la fuente de error cuando lo reformes (para ti ignorada e imposible de depurar, aunque sea temporalmente).

Tal se vé en el programa que da el fallo, algo perturba el vector cuando se salva, y no hay en el programa entre su estado inicial al grabarse y el perturbado visto al recobrarlo nada que proceda de la acción del programador para que se dé, que es lo que lo hace misterioso para un programador ajeno al funcionamiento de interno de freebasic ...¿reescritura aparte con inicialización en memoria? ... ¿error de transcripción de cualquier causa? ... ¿caída de segmentos en paralelización por mal timing? y miles de cosas arcanas para gente como yo con modestísimo alcance en programación.

Comment: Hola Manuel, te recomiendo que revises tu pregunta y pongas lo que has intentado, si no quieres que tu pregunta sea cerrada.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Hola, Alfabravo, el código mínimo son las tres sentencias de abrir el canal, pasar el vector, y cerrarlo; es lo que no funciona (como debería) siguiendo al establecimiento del vector a guardar. Mi solución para otros casos de fallo de guardar así ha sido revisar mi programa, reconstruyéndolo y depurándolo, pero no tengo una idea clara de porqué esto sucede ni en este ni casos anteriores.  Comprendo que cualquier tema que   llama a averiguar el porqué pide al menos ver código, pero de momento no debo por ser el ápex de un trabajo perseguido por 43 años.

Comment: Alfabravo, más propiamente, el algoritmo que está causando esta dificultad será un componente optativo frecuente de cierta importancia en los códigos de cifrado, pero realmente (típicamente) no el más determinante  ni poderoso.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya he indicado la manera que resolví este problema en anteriores ocasiones fué reescribir el programa, y lo he hecho otra vez. Mejor descrito, y dado que estoy construyendo los bloques que formarán en su momento el sistema de cifrado del que estoy efectuando el port a freebasic, he buscado entre mis programas un par (Cifrado / Descifrado) similares a los del componente en su día a utilizar y que no daba el problema al salvar con Put (ni al recobrar con Get) y en cuanto a base para definir (al menos este tipo de componentes) problema resuelto. Put graba bien y Get recobra bien. Me queda pues expedito el seguir con la construcción del sistema.

---

Al proseguir haciendo módulos para el sistema, he encontrado dificultades diferentes en el uso de Put. Sin embargo en estos casos he podido trazar causa, en este caso fallos del programador, tipo despiste, a los que conviene prestar atención para evitarlo.

Fallo tipo 1. Pese a haber corrido el programa con éxito en versión anterior, alguna variación del mismo ha puesto la creación del nombre del archivo en que se va a guardar más abajo del Put al que el respectivo canal apunta. O sea, asegurarse de que el nombre del archivo de guardado está declarado y definido, pues sin nombre no se puede guardar.

Fallo tipo 2. El archivo en que guardar está declarado y definido correctamente, pero tal archivo está abierto por (típicamente) otro programa que le mantiene cerrado a modificaciones. No tengo por cierto si tal cosa ha sucedido de alguna forma con el mismo FBide o quizás desde algún otro IDE que rarísimamente abro; en mi caso era los más de los casos un programa que da estadísticas del archivo cifrado (cosa de escasa importancia al cifrado, pues lo importante de un cifrado no es tener precisas conformaciones estadísticas, sino ser difícil de descifrar). En una ocasión (pero en las demás no) he visto un mensaje del debugger de FBide indicando el problema.

Fallo tipo 3. (inseguro efecto). El end del programa no viene seguido de CR-LF, con lo que no figura en negrita. El programa corría pero no he tenido ocasión todavía la ocasión de saber adecuadamente acerca de los efectos de tal cosa, que, sin embargo, me ha parecido causa fallo en el (inmediatamente anterior) intento de salvado por Put.

A resultas de estos fallos de programación, el fallo que sigue sin explicación es el que figura en las imágenes: Put salva, pero mal. Es el caso en que conserva sólo el primer Byte, el 272. Estimo que las 3 explicaciones de arriba deberían cubrir la mayoría de las incidencias que he tenido con Put.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).